# How to change every character in string to be 'n' ahead?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, ascii, stdstring

I want to change every character in string `a` to be `n` ahead, by adding each `char`acter of the string to `n`.

For example:

```
std::string a = "abcdefghi" 
int n = 5
```

then the output will be `"fghijklmn"`.

**My Problem**:
My code doesn't work for characters above `127` in *ASCII*. any clue?
I'm looking for the bug in my code, not for other solutions.

**This is my code**

```
string a; cin >> a;
int n;    cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
{
    a[i] = a[i] + n;
    if (a[i] > 122)
    {
        a[i] %= 122;
        a[i] += 96;
    }
}
cout << a << endl;
```

Comment: ASCII doesn't have characters above 127. But aside from that, when it "doesn't work", what is the input, what is the expected output, and what is the problem that you see?

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ caesar cipher".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to add `n` to each element(which are `char`s) of the string `a` and have a problem when it exceeds the maximum value of alphabets in [ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html). i.e. ASCII corresponding to the letter `z` which is `122`. 
In that case, you want to start again from the letter `a`.
For example:

**input**:

```
stuvwxyz // a
5        // n
```

**output**:

```
xyzabcde
```

If so following is the problem.

Consider `a` be `std::string a{ "z" };` When you do this

```
a[i] = a[i] + n;
```

you have already added the `n` to the character and exceeded the maximum limit, regardless, what the character in `a[i]`. That means you need to do that only when it is not the case of `a[i] + n > 122`.

Simply assign the change to each character of the string `a`, after the necessary steps in the if-condition.

*([See here for a 
demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VAfYCUmbpd7wjSet))*

```
short n = 5;                 // std::cin >> n;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
{
    short  res = static_cast<short>(a[i]) + n;
    if (res > 122)
    {
        res %= 122;
        res += 96;
    }
    a[i] = static_cast<char>(res);
}
```

Comment: I would use an `int` instead of a `char` for the adding, and then `if (a[i] + n > 122)` can be changed to `if (res > 122)`. Either way, `a[i] = (res += 96);` can be changed to just `res += 96;` and then drop the `else`, always do `a[i] = res;` unconditionally. `int res = a[i] + n; if (res > 122) { res %= 122; res += 96; } a[i] = (char) res;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right. I didn't think of that. Thanks for the suggestion. edited as per.